# Ptyhon: how to compute mean and percentiles over a list of arrays avoiding zeros

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working with satellite images that are `geotiff` files in form of arrays. Let say that I have multiple images with blank spaces (because of clouds or other elements). However I am collecting those arrays in a list.

```
from rasterio.plot import show
LST = [array1, array2]
f,ax=plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=[20,20])
show(lst_paris2, cmap='hot_r', vmin=vmin, ax=ax[0])
show(lst_paris3, cmap='hot_r', vmin=vmin1, ax=ax[1])
```

[image]

I would like to compute, for each pixel (i.e. cell `i,j` of the array) the `mean` as `numpy.mean(LST)`and the `percentiles` as `numpy.percentile(LIST, [5,50,95])` avoiding the zeros values.

Comment: So you want to keep only the pixel values that are non-zero?

Comment: Let's say array1 is already a numpy array. Then `array1[array1 != 0]` gives you the non-zero array

Comment: Are all your arrays in the `LIST` of same shape?

Comment: @Ehsan yes they are

Answer (score 1):

Your `LST` variable seems to be a list of two lists/arrays. It would help if you use `np.hstack` to make a single `np.array` from those two lists. Then you can make calculations like @midtownguru stated in comments.

```py
array1 = [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10]
array2 = [15,16,17,18,19]
# Stack two arrays to make a single np.array
LST = np.hstack([array1, array2])
print(LST.shape)
>>> (24,)

# Now you can calculate mean, percentile etc. without 0's
np.mean(LST[LST != 0])
>>> 5.5
np.percentile(LST[LST != 0], [5, 85])
>>> array([1.45, 8.65])
```

Comment: I wan the average of each pixel not the total average

Comment: You have two values for each pixel. So how will you compute percentiles?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .nonzero() method with boolean indexing

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.asarray(LST)
np.percentile(lst[lst.nonzero()], [5, 50, 95])
```